# Enable to scale a ImageData from a CanvasRenderingContext2D into a other one

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here I have my main canvas 2D context that is on my screen named baseCtx that is in the custom service drawingService.

zoomCtx is the CanvasRenderingContext2D of my second canvas and zoomCanvas is the HTMLCanvasElement of my secondary canvas.

I want to take a rectangle that is the size of a smaller canvas that have for center my mouse.

CurrentX and CurrentY are the current mousePosition on my main canvas.

That is working just fine I can see the content of the rectangle zone on the secondary canvas.

The problem come when I try to zoom in the secondary canvas that will play the role of a magnifying glass. I can see the zone around my cursor drawing on the secondary canvas, it is just not zoom in.

I just won't zoom event tho I am using the scale method.

Here is my code that is called each time the mouse move

```js
calculateZoomedPixel() {
    let sx = this.currentX - this.zoomCanvas.width / 2;
    let sy = this.currentY - this.zoomCanvas.height / 2;
    const zoom = 2;

    let image = this.drawingService.baseCtx.getImageData(sx, sy,   this.zoomCanvas.width, this.zoomCanvas.height);
    this.zoomCtx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
    this.zoomCtx.translate(zoom * this.zoomCanvas.width, zoom *   this.zoomCanvas.height);
    this.zoomCtx.scale(zoom, zoom);
    this.zoomCtx.drawImage(this.zoomCanvas, 0, 0);
    this.zoomCtx.translate(-zoom * this.zoomCanvas.width, -zoom *   this.zoomCanvas.height);
}
```

Here is an example of what i want the second canvas to look like:

[image]

And here is an example of my application (The smaller canvas to the left should be zoom in):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems here:

- Your translate calls are not made properly, you are only translating back **after** you drew the image, which has no good effect.
- You never reset the transformation matrix after you set its scale, so at second call, your zoom canvas as its scale set to 4, at third, to 8 etc.

To workaround both these problems, you can use the absolute `setTransform()` method to set both the scale and the translate in one call, and then translate back using the `drawImage`'s parameters:

```js
const source_width = source.width = 500;
const source_height = source.height = 500;
const mag_width = magnifier.width = 100;
const mag_height = magnifier.height = 100;

const source_ctx = source.getContext("2d");
source_ctx.fillStyle = "white";
source_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, source_width, source_height);
source_ctx.stroke(randomLines());
const mag_ctx = magnifier.getContext("2d");
mag_ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
mag_ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";

source.onmousemove = (evt) => {
  const rect = source.getBoundingClientRect();
  const current_x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  const current_y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
  const sx = current_x - mag_width / 2;
  const sy = current_y - mag_height / 2;
  const zoom = 10;

  const image = source_ctx.getImageData(sx, sy, mag_width, mag_height);
  mag_ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
  // set the zoom and translate to center in one call
  mag_ctx.setTransform(zoom, 0, 0, zoom, mag_width/2, mag_height/2 );
  // translate back in drawImage to center our image
  mag_ctx.drawImage(magnifier, -mag_width/2, -mag_height/2);
  // reset to identity matrix
  mag_ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
};


function randomLines() {
  const path = new Path2D();
  for( let i = 0; i<30; i++ ) {
    const x = Math.random() * source_width;
    const y = Math.random() * source_height;
    path.lineTo(x, y);
  }
  return path;
}
```

```css
#magnifier { position: absolute; border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<canvas id="magnifier"></canvas>
<canvas id="source"></canvas>
```

But you should not call `getImageData` in a mousemove event like this. `getImageData` is utterly slow as it requires to move the context's buffer from the GPU to the CPU. Call it only once to grab the full canvas and reuse only that single ImageData:

```js
const source_width = source.width = 500;
const source_height = source.height = 500;
const mag_width = magnifier.width = 100;
const mag_height = magnifier.height = 100;

const source_ctx = source.getContext("2d");
source_ctx.fillStyle = "white";
source_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, source_width, source_height);
source_ctx.stroke(randomLines());
const mag_ctx = magnifier.getContext("2d");
mag_ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

// get the image data only once, when the drawing is done
const image = source_ctx.getImageData(0, 0, source_width, source_height );

source.onmousemove = (evt) => {
  mag_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, mag_width, mag_height);
  const rect = source.getBoundingClientRect();
  const current_x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  const current_y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
  const sx = current_x - mag_width / 2;
  const sy = current_y - mag_height / 2;
  const zoom = 10;
  // draw the correct portion of the ImageData
  mag_ctx.putImageData(image, -sx, -sy, sx, sy, source_width, source_height);
  // set the zoom and translate to center in one call
  mag_ctx.setTransform(zoom, 0, 0, zoom, mag_width/2, mag_height/2 );
  // translate back in drawImage to center our image
  mag_ctx.drawImage(magnifier, -mag_width/2, -mag_height/2);
  // reset to identity matrix
  mag_ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
};


function randomLines() {
  const path = new Path2D();
  for( let i = 0; i<30; i++ ) {
    const x = Math.random() * source_width;
    const y = Math.random() * source_height;
    path.lineTo(x, y);
  }
  return path;
}
```

```css
#magnifier { position: absolute; border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<canvas id="magnifier"></canvas>
<canvas id="source"></canvas>
```

And if you are not doing anything with these pixels' data, then just use `drawImage` directly:

```js
const source_width = source.width = 500;
const source_height = source.height = 500;
const mag_width = magnifier.width = 100;
const mag_height = magnifier.height = 100;

const source_ctx = source.getContext("2d");
source_ctx.fillStyle = "white";
source_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, source_width, source_height);
source_ctx.stroke(randomLines());
const mag_ctx = magnifier.getContext("2d");
mag_ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

source.onmousemove = (evt) => {
  mag_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, mag_width, mag_height);
  const rect = source.getBoundingClientRect();
  const current_x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  const current_y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
  const sx = current_x - mag_width / 2;
  const sy = current_y - mag_height / 2;
  const zoom = 10;

  mag_ctx.setTransform(zoom, 0, 0, zoom, mag_width/2, mag_height/2 );
  // draw source canvas directly
  mag_ctx.drawImage(source, sx, sy, mag_width, mag_height, -mag_width/2, -mag_height/2, mag_width, mag_height);

  // reset to identity matrix
  mag_ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
};


function randomLines() {
  const path = new Path2D();
  for( let i = 0; i<30; i++ ) {
    const x = Math.random() * source_width;
    const y = Math.random() * source_height;
    path.lineTo(x, y);
  }
  return path;
}
```

```css
#magnifier { position: absolute; border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<canvas id="magnifier"></canvas>
<canvas id="source"></canvas>
```

Comment: THank you so much ! I went with the third option that do not use getImage et putImage for better performance and it works super great ! A life savor :D